# How to know which type of file system my Android device uses

Tags: android

I want to know which type of file system my Android device uses.

Does it use [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) or [Yaffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAFFS)?

Also, how do I view the file system properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Activate USB debugging](https://www.lifewire.com/enable-usb-debugging-android-4690927) on your phone.
2. Connect your phone via USB to your computer. The phone should display a message like "USB debugging connected".
3. Run [`adb shell`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) in your computer's terminal.
4. Inside the ADB shell, run [`mount`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html). This will show all the mount points and their file system type:

[image: screenshot after running mount inside ADB shell]

Comment: What? how to goto command prompt in mobile I really don't know

Comment: So you don't have adb shell installed in your computer... no problem, goto play.google.com and install a terminal emulator ,after that you have to open the terminal and just type mount

Comment: it's written like /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system yaffs2 ro 0 0 here the file system is yaffs